# HTML easy (and touch compatible) drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p {
    font-family: "Comic Sans",sans-serif;
}
#div1 {   
    width: 7.5%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    padding: 3%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
    background-color: white;
    float:right;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0px;
}
#div2 {
    width: 7.5%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 15%;
    padding: 3%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0px;
}
#div3 {
    width: 7.5%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 30%;
    padding: 3%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0px;
}
#div4 {
    width: 101px;
    height: 101px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    padding: 1%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 0px 25px 25px 0px;
    background-color: white;
}
#div5 {
    height: 101px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 0px 25px 25px 25px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 1.5%;
}
#text {
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 13%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    color: #417cb8;
    text-align: center;
}
#tag1 {
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    padding: 1px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    width: 13%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-family: "Comic Sans",sans-serif;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #417cb8;
}
#tag2 {
    margin-right: 15%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    width: 13%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Comic Sans",sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    right: 0px;
    color: #417cb8;

}
#tag3 {
    margin-right: 30%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    width: 13%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Comic Sans",sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    right: 0px;
    color: #417cb8;
}
#tag4 {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    width: 10%;
    height: 101px;
    border-radius: 25px 0px 0px 25px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Comic Sans",sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    color: #417cb8;
    padding: 1%;
}
#element {
 float: left;
}
img.object {
 border: 1px solid #6496c8;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 height: 101px;
 width: 101px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#element').draggable();
    $( "#div1" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
          $( this )
            .addClass( "isDropped" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
        }
      });
    });

</script> <script>
function allowDrop(ev, div) {
    ev.preventDefault()
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id)
}

function drop(ev, div) {
    ev.preventDefault()
 if(div == 'div4') 
 {
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text")
  var element = document.getElementById(data)
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
 }
 else if (div == 'div5') {
  if(document.getElementById(div).innerHTML <= 5)
  {
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text")
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))
  }
 }
 else if (div == 'element')
 {
  
 }
 else
 {
  if(document.getElementById(div).innerHTML <= 5)
  {
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text")
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))
  }
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<div style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 30px; background-color: #6496c8;">
<body>

<h2 style="float: center; text-align: center; border-bottom: 4px solid black; width: 275px; height: 65px; border-radius: 25px 0px 0px 0px; background-color: white; margin-left: 1.5%;"><font style="text-align:center;" face="verdana" color="#417cb8" size=30>Organiser</font></h2>

<div id="tag1"><font size="7">Now</font></div><br><br><br><br>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event, 'div1')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div1')"></div>

<div id="tag2"><font size="7">Next</font></div><br><br><br><br>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event, 'div2')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div2')"></div>
<div id="tag3"><font size="7">After</font></div><br><br><br><br>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event, 'div3')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div3')"></div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p id="text"><font size="7">To Do</font></p>

<p id="div5" ondrop="drop(event, 'div1')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div1')" overflow="Scroll">
<img class="object" src="ABC.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="100" height="100">
<img class="object" src="pencil.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" width="100" height="100">
<img class="object" src="recycle.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3" width="100" height="100">
<img class="object" src="apple.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag4" width="100" height="100">

<br><br><p><div id = "tag4"><font size="10">Done</font></div></p>
<div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event, 'div4')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div4')"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/tools-solid-icons-vol-2/72/59-512.png" height=100px width=100px></div><br>


</body>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

When I try to drag and drop on a mobile device, it does not do anything... Is it an apple specific problem or is it a problem with the code? It works on a PC and MAC... I tried to search but have found no real answers that are simple to implement (I dont wanna rewrite 90% of the code)

Comment: you still never fixed your css float: center;  I told you in the other thread that it is not a proper css code.  https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator  your errors

Comment: 2  #h1  Value Error : float center is not a float value : center
5  h2  Value Error : float center is not a float value : center
149  img.object  Value Error : height only 0 can be a unit. You must put a unit after your number : 101
150  img.object  Value Error : width only 0 can be a unit. You must put a unit after your number : 101
151  img.object  Value Error : float center is not a float value : center
151  img.object  Parse Error [empty string]

Comment: I'm so sorry! I had these two ready to post within seconds of each other... Didn't let me post and first thing i did when i got home was post this and look at responses!

Comment: it's no big deal to me,

Comment: I fixed up the code for those errors... When I tested it was fine... I only fix up completely on final products generally

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few errors that I can see:

1. draggable="true" is an HTML5 tag that can which makes the element draggable. Also the events that you've attached to it, the drag Events (namely dragstart, drag, dragenter, dragleave, dragover, drop, dragend) work only on mouse enabled devices. For touch devices (mobile/surface) you have touch events (namely touchstart, touchmove, touchend, touchcancel)
2. Since you're using jQueryUI, you should checkout their way using draggable() and droppable(). I don't know why you've mixed HTML5 drag with jQueryUI's method of drag and drop.
3. Touch Punch library works with elements which are made draggable using jQueryUI's functions.
4. I don't see any div with id="element" in the whole page. Element on which you've attached .draggable() and .droppable()

I found the following links helpful in understanding the drag and drop:

1. HTML5: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/
2. jQueryUI DnD: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/ (The Documentation is self explanatory. Also the demos are straight forward)
3. Pure JS based drag and drop: https://github.com/lukasolson/drag-n-drop-js

Hope that helps